# Can I use "Spring Data JDBC" with Spring Boot 1.5.x?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I have tried to figure out which version of spring-data-jdbc to use with Spring Boot 1.5.20.RELEASE (= Spring Framework 4.3.23.RELEASE) - but I  can't find that info anywhere.

Is it because spring-data-jdbc only work with Spring Boot 2.x / Spring Framework 5.x?

Specifically I want to use `@Query`, `@EnableJdbcRepositories`, etc.

When I look at the release notes for Spring Data Ingalls SR20 (the release train that matches Boot 1.5.20.RELEASE / Framework 4.3.23.RELEASE) it looks like spring-data-jdbc is only supported in Lovelace (Boot 2.x and Framework 5.x): https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/10/spring-data-lovelace-sr6-kay-sr14-ingalls-sr20-released

EDIT & ANSWER: As per comment from @JensSchauder: spring-data-jdbc is a (fairly) new project created from scratch. There is no way to use it with Spring Framework 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `spring-data-jdbc` `pom.xml` it uses `spring-data-parent` to manage Spring Framework version by defining and applying `spring.version` property. You must ensure that this Spring Framework version is compatible with whatever version you are using.

The first available `spring-data-jdbc:1.0.0.RELEASE` version uses [`spring-data-parent:2.1.0.RELEASE`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.data.build/spring-data-parent/2.1.0.RELEASE/pom) parent which requires Spring Framework 5.1:

```
<spring>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring>
```

It's not be recommended to use `spring-data-jdbc` with lower Spring Framework version. Since Spring Boot 1.5.X uses Spring Framework 4.X the answer would be no.

Comment: So no way of using anything like `@Query` and `@EnableJdbcRepositories` with JDBC repositories unless we upgrade to Spring Framework 5.1.x? I was hoping the `spring-data-jdbc` had just been renamed or extracted from another module, or something similar...

Comment: @RasmusLund Are you using Maven or Gradle? You should be using the spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency. Spring Boot 1.x will then pull in the spring-jdbc package rather than spring-data-jdbc.

Comment: @Gimby ...but that will just give me access to the "old" JDBC support stuff like JdbcTemplate - and not any Spring Data specific support - or??

Comment: @RasmusLund then you likely need spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. The point is: use starters.

Comment: @Gimby I don't want JPA - I want JDBC :-/

Comment: @RasmusLund spring-data-jdbc is a (fairly) new project created from scratch. There is no way to use it with Spring Framework 4 and there is no "old version" or "predecessor"